# Typeahead remote call shows a subset of results

Tags: autocomplete, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I'm trying to use [typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) to get a list of authors from my own server (flask endpoint). When I use `local` source for Bloodhound everything works smoothly, only when I have to fetch the data from a server not all the results seem to be shown.

So this is the code:

```js
var authors = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    // local: ["Aad, Georges", "Abajyan, Tatevik", "Abbott, Brad"],

    remote: {
        url: '/search/authors?q=%QUERY',
        transform: function (json) {
            var names = $.map(json.results, function (author) {
                return author.full_name;
            });
            console.log(names);
            return names;
        }
    }
});

$('#author-suggest').typeahead(null, {
    source: authors
});
```

I make sure to print the names that come back from the url and they seem to be identical to what I might put into the local variable:

```
$ Array [ "Aad, Georges", "Abajyan, Tatevik", "Abbott, Brad" ]
$ Array [ "Aad, Georges", "Abajyan, Tatevik", "Abbott, Brad" ]
…
```

Yet something strange happens when I test it. When I try to type in the `input` box - I get suggestions, however it's only a subset of those printed in the console. They also don't dynamically change when I type (`Aad, Georges` is still the first suggestion even when I'm already at `"Abbott"`).

The other peculiar thing is that not all of the names are being suggested, even though all of them have clearly came back from the server. When the server sends 3 names, only the first 2 are in the suggestions. When it sends 4 names, 1 suggestion appears. The general pattern is:

```
[(1 -> 1), (2 -> 2), (3 -> 2), (4 -> 1), (5 -> 0), (6 -> 5), (7 -> 5)… ]
```

Where the first number in a pair represents the number of authors received and the second is the number of suggestions. What the heck is going on here?!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm seeing something similar with remote data (haven't tested local), and it's driving me bonkers. You ever sort this out?

Comment: I think I finally solved it, but don't remember how. Try adding `wildcard: '%QUERY'` to the `remote` Bloodhound field and `valueKey: 'symbol'` in the typeahead object definition (next to the `source` field). Maybe one of these'll help